# Ez Publish Language switcher

Tags: ezpublish

Is it possible that when i  switch to another language , get same content  from where i'm switching ?

for example: 
if i'm  on English page `"http://englishDomain.com/en/News/someNews/SomeChildOfNews"`
and when i switch to German content i want to get like this `"http://germanDomain.com/de/NewsOnGermanLanguage/SomeChildOfNewsOnGermanLanguage`

as you can see on my example i want same content on German language   and      "slug"  should be  on German too

any links or tutorial examples will be helpful for me

---

I found this  in DOC (https://doc.ez.no/display/EZP/Language+Switcher)  but  this code not working , it gives me a same url where i am.

```
$routeRefGenerator = $this->get( 'ezpublish.route_reference.generator' );
$routeRef = $routeRefGenerator->generate( $location, array( 'language' => 'fre-FR' ) );
$link = $this->generateUrl( $routeRef );
```

Comment: in English translation you have an Object "News", If you edit the same Object in GERMAN and in the German version change the name to "NewsOnGermanLanguage" and the same for "someNews" and "SomeChildOfNews", you will get exactly what you want even without code.
did I understand you right ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
$link = $this->get( 'ezpublish.chain_router')->generate( $location, array('siteaccess' => 'de') );
```